# Haskell: How to implement >>= for a parser

Tags: parsing, haskell, monads

I have the following Parser

```
newtype Parser a = P (String -> [(a,String)])
```

and I need to implement the bind on its implementation as a Monad.  I have that the return is defined as

```
instance Monad Parser where
    return v = P (\inp -> [(v,inp)])
```

To implement `p >>= f` I know this much: `p` is a Parser object and f has type declaration

```
f :: a -> Parser b
```

So I'm thinking the value of `p >>= f` needs to be a Parser object which wraps a function.  That function's argument is a String.  So I'm guessing the function should "open up `p`", get its function, apply that to the input string, get an object of type [(a, String)], then ... I guess maybe apply `f` to every first coordinate in each tuple, then use the resulting Parser's function and apply it to the second coordinate ... and make a list of all of those tuples?

At this point I get pretty foggy on whether I got this right and if so, how to do it.  Maybe I should write a helper function with type

```
trans :: [(a,String)] -> (a -> Parser b) -> [(b,String)]
```

But before getting into that, I wanted to check if my confused description of what I should be doing rings true.

Comment: Hint: what is a bind for list?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem `fmap`.  Is the hint that `trans` should make use of `fmap`?  Or should is it suggesting that I not create this `trans` function at all and `fmap` does everything for me?

Comment: Your informal description looks right to me. Try to turn that into code.

Comment: @Addem: no, the bind of a list is `concatMap`, and it is quite similar here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
instance Monad Parser where
    return v = P (\inp -> [(v,inp)])
    P p >>= f = P (\inp -> do
        (x,u) <- p inp
        let P q = f x
        q u
        )
```

Comment: `p inp` has type `[(a,String)]`, right?  Is the do-notation just grabbing the first element of the list if it exists?  Does this mean everything else gets thrown away, if it exists?

Comment: @Addem `do`-notation is a syntactic sugar for any monadic action. Here, it is for a list monad. As a consequence, `(x,u)` represents *every* element of `p inp`.

Comment: Oh, this is due to the fact that bind for list is concatMap which iterates over the elements of the list?

Comment: @Addem Yes, exactly.

Comment: @Addem In the list monad, `do` is essentially another syntax for list comprehensions: `... = P (\inp -> [r | (x,u) <- p inp , let P q = f x , r <- q u])` is equivalent.